# In SSRS, is it possible to loop one subreport rdl from a master rdl without using C#?

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I'm having a problem using a subreport inside a Master page.  My Master page has 4 parameters with one parameter that varies.

The one subreport inside the Master page will take 3 parameters that are constant and the 4th parameter will change by way of a loop.  The output will create many reports generated from the 4 parameter.

How do you create a loop from the Master page changing the value of the 4th parameter to run the subreport as many times as there are values in the 4 parameter?

The Main Report (Main.rdl)
Parameters
  WidgetID
  RegionID
  TimePeriodID

The query will get the distinct StateIDs

The SubReport (subreport.rdl)
Parameters
  WidgetID
  RegionID
  TimePeriodID
  StateID

The report has 5 lines of headers with all of the parameters in the header, including the first state name.  The detail line with have all of the widget information inside that state.

Then loop to get the next StateID and repeat the output as before.

Then continue until all of the StateIDs are processes.

I cannot group by State since that has to be in the header.

Taking the advice from Dominic I tried to follow his instructions.

**Main.rdl**

Created a Table via Toolbox and put the subreport in the first data column.

Added 3 Parameters

Dataset output

**SubReport.rdl**

Added 3 Parameters

Dataset output

When I Preview Main1.rdl, I get the first row and then new page.  Second row and then new page.

What I am trying to get is a new page after change in State Code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a dataset that will return rows according to your parameters, and then include your subreport in a table that is bound to that dataset.

Comment: Dominic, Let me try it out.  I'll do some research on how to bind a table to a dataset.  I'm a newbie to ssrs.

Comment: Dominic, I appended my question to include what you told me this morning.

Comment: I resolved the new page problem.  Now I am getting the complete dataset multiple times (5 states results in 5 identical datasets being displayed).

Comment: I just put the subreport in a rectangle and I now have the dataset showing up once.  I just need to figure out how to create a new page on state change.  The entire dataset is showing on one page.  Group Properties on the subreport by state did not work and I cannot do an Add Group since the state can only be in the header.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem and I've had some trouble with creating the right dataset because I've been working with MDX to access my cube. If you use SQL, this isn't relevant, but I'm adding this because a lot of gents use MDX.
What I eventually did:

-Let my parameter and its dataset get generated automatically (MDX)
-Make my tablix to put my subreport in
-Link this tablix to the parameter's dataset
-Put a filter on the tablix: - ParameterValue "IN" "=Parameters!parameterName.Value"

Be sure to 
-use "IN" and not "=" 
-use "=Parameters!SLASLANAME.Value" and not "=Parameters!SLASLANAME.Value**(0)**" in your expression

Comment: I ended up using Patrick LeBlanc's example. http://www.bidn.com/blogs/PatrickLeBlanc/ssis/762/ssrs-r2-naming-excel-worksheet-tabs His solution gave to correct code on the spreadsheet tab and Tablix header, but when I exported the SSRS report to Excel the spreadsheet tab had the correct code values, but the Tablix header defalted to the first code in the dataset collection. My workaround was to put the code value in the report header so that I could use ReportItems![Field Name].Value.  Only one rdl was required to give me the correct value and I never had to use a sub-report.